# ISO narrow-wide steel chainrings in higher tooth counts >30T

Tags: drivetrain, steel, alternative-drivetrain

I know Surly, Sram, RaceFace and Wolf Tooth have offerings in small BCD and proprietary fixing systems (cinch & X-sync), but generally only come in one, MTB-range size.
Anyone know of a manufacturer with something more suitable to road/gravel drivetrains? i.e. 38+ teeth, 110/130BCD? Must be stainless steel!

Comment: Vote to close, answers are making this nothing more than a shopping question.

Answer (score 1):

Specific product recommendations are off topic here. However, we can point you in the right direction. At the time of writing SRAM makes 1x drivetrains for road, gravel or cyclocross bikes.

Perhaps start with SRAM [Apex-1](https://www.sram.com/sram/road/family/sram-apex-1) or [Rival-1](https://www.sram.com/sram/road/family/sram-rival-1).

Comment: OK oops.. 
All Sram 1x road drivetrains use alloy chainrings

Comment: At least SRAM offers 1x cranks with symmetrical 110mm BCD rather than MTB oriented 104mm. Next step is to find a 3rd party chainring maker that offers steel 110mm BCD rings.

Comment: Custom machining time!

Comment: Yeah! Just break out the Tormach

Answer (score 0):

Check your online stores again.  Surly produces 110-130BCD stainless steel chainrings in a variety of sizes.

https://surlybikes.com/parts/drivetrain/stainless_steel_chainrings

Comment: But they are not narrow-wide! The question is whether there is a chainring that is both steel, narrow-wide, has many teeth and possibly 104BCD. I personally cannot even find one that satisfies the first two conditions.